# Give three examples of groups of order 120, no two of which are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Give three examples of groups of order 120, no two of which are isomorphic. Explain why they are not isomorphic. (This is Exercise 57 from Chapter 6 of the book *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* by Gallian.)

**My Attempt:**

$\mathbb Z_{120} $

$\mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{60}$

$\mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{2}\times \mathbb Z_{30} $

These are group of order 120, but I don't know if these are the isomorphic or not. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct!

One can show that the order of an element $(g_1, g_2,..., g_n)$ in a direct product of groups $G_1 \times G_2 \times \cdots \times G_n$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(|g_1|, |g_2|, ..., |g_n|)$.

Given this, think about $\max \{ \operatorname{ord}(g) \ | \ g \in G\}$ for each of the groups you've listed (orders would be preserved under isomorphism).

---

Alternatively, there are small nonabelian groups of orders dividing $120$, allowing you to construct nonabelian groups of order $120$ via a direct product (abelian-ness should be preserved under isomorphism).  You can even get a nonabelian group of order $120$ directly by considering the symmetry group of an $n$-gon for appropriately-sized $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If there were an isomorphism, all orders of elements would be preserved. Does the second group have an element of order 120? How many elements of order 2 are there in each?